# Dual Boot isssues: Bootable usb not finding NVMe drive in computer

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot, nvme

I am trying to dual boot my XPS 13 (9350) with Windows 10 and Ubuntu (latest LTR) . Windows is already installed. The storage device in my computer is: NVMe PM951 NVMe SAMSU

What I have done:
Created a UEFI bootable usb with Ubuntu on it. (Using Rufis and GPT partitioning) I am able to boot in UEFI mode from the usb. However, on the install, I get the issues where the usb does not recognize my drive. (issue detailed [here](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN299303/en)) 
Said article suggests switching from RAID to AHCI mode. While I do have backups of everything, switching modes seems very time consuming, and I have work to do, so I want to use my time as efficiently as possible. Lastly, I've found no method of switching that I'm confident in)
I'm more interested in the other suggested fix, which is to use the second part of [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man4/nvme.4freebsd.html) to add a boot load argument (nvme_load="YES"). I've tried it, but nothing changed. I've tried to look up more about having my bootable usb load up the driver I need on boot, but I've found very little that makes sense.

TLDR:
my options are:
1) switch from RAID to AHCI
2) modify my boot options on my bootable usb with ubuntu on it.

my question:
Is it possible to modify my boot options on my usb so that they contain the drivers for my drive from boot so I do not have to switch from raid? If so, how?

Comment: Switching modes takes seconds in your UEFI settings but you should first install AHCI drivers in Windows 10 otherwise it won't boot in AHCI mode. Everything is trivial as long as you know what you're doing. And if you don't then you shouldn't be installing OSes.

Comment: Thank you for the advice about installing the AHCI drivers. I ended up biting the bullet and using safemode to switch from RAID to AHCI. In response to your other piece of advice, I appreciate the warning, and you're right that I shouldn't just muck around, but responding to a question on a helpsite with "everything is trival, and if you don't know what you're doing you shouldn't be doing it" sure is ironic.

Comment: Not an answer, just a comment. The "answers" field is intended to provide answers. Comments are for clarification and/or to point to a better solution or reorient. Since you actually didn't ask an (answerable) question I merely stated what you would need to do to have a working dual-boot system. If you don't know know how to do what I suggested you can ask another specific question, that one having a better chance to get an answer.

Comment: Although my issue is fixed, I’d greatly appreciate some feedback on why my post “didn’t as an (answerable) question” so that next time my post makes enough sense that folks can respond with solutions. (As well as any other feedback you have to give)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I did end up switching from RAID to AHCI. I did so following the tutorial at https://gist.github.com/chenxiaolong/4beec93c464639a19ad82eeccc828c63 . This worked like a charm and was all I had to do to solve my probIem.